# How can I (re)load the textedit view of a macOS app from an OCR function?

Tags: macos, swiftui, ocr

I am trying to build an Xcode macOS shopping app using the document app builder and have added an OCR function. Within the function calling the OCR Vision function, I can save the text into a file. I can open that file in a new app instance into the document text editor of the doc app.

Is it possible to overwrite the blank untitled content view / doc view view without closing the current instance of the app with the text from the OCR output? In the code below, I have replaced the normal `$document.text` provided by the app with my var `myText`.

At the simplest, here is the code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  myGrocery
//
//  Created by Erick J Camp on 5/18/23.
//

import SwiftUI
var a = "myTest"
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: myGroceryDocument
    @State var myText = a

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Button("OCR") {
                a = ocr()
                print(a) //debug view show expected text.
            }
            
            //TextEditor(text: $document.text)
            TextEditor(text: $myText)
            processed().frame(maxWidth: 200, alignment: .top)
        }
    }
}

struct processed: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello").frame(alignment: .top)
        Spacer()
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(document: .constant(myGroceryDocument()))
    }
}
func ocr() -> String {
    return "this is a test"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found I could do what I wanted by adding and environmentObject.  Here is the code I used.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  myGrocery
//
//  Created by Erick J Camp on 5/18/23.
//

import SwiftUI

final class someText: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewText = "H E LL O"
}

struct processed: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myText: someText
    var body: some View {
        Text(myText.viewText).frame(alignment: .top)
        Spacer()
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: myGroceryDocument
    @StateObject var myText = someText()

    var body: some View {
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    Button("OCR") {
                        myText.viewText = "\($document.text)"
                        print(myText.viewText)
                        myText.viewText = ocr()
                        print(myText.viewText) //debug view show expected text.
                        document.text = myText.viewText
                    }.padding(5)
                    Spacer()
                }
            //TextEditor(text: $document.text)
            TextEditor(text: $myText.viewText)
                VStack{
                    processed().frame( maxWidth: 200)
                        //.padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .environmentObject(myText)
            }
    }
}
func ocr() -> String {
    return "this is a test"
}

/*
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(document: .constant(myGroceryDocument()))
    }
}
*/
```